# Authentication error in openStack's Horizon dashboard

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, virtualbox, openstack, windows-10

I'm trying to setup an openStack controller from a VirtualBox VM. My VirtualBox host is Windows 10 and the guest is Ubuntu Server 14. The guest should (someday) function as an openStack controller, and it should control a Compute node running on some x86 located somewhere in my network (I should later on control it through it's IP). Right now - I'm still in the earlier stage of trying to log on to my Horizon dashboard, but I keep getting an authentication error when I try to log into the openStack dashboard.

To sum it up:

- Running on Windows 10 as a host, where I made a bridge between my local Ethernet adapter, and VirtualBox's virtual Ethernet adapter. This way all machines are able to ping each other.
- I'm running an Ubuntu Server 14, on VirtualBox 5
- All machines can ping each other, and I can reach the Horizon dashboard log-in screen when I enter `<IP>/horizon` in my web browser.
- Upon entering username and password in dashboard - I get: `An error occurred authenticating. Please try again later.`

I've gone through numerous trials and ways to solve this - going through https://ask.openstack.org/en/questions/ , https://askubuntu.com/ , https://www.virtualbox.org ,  https://superuser.com/ and probably anything I could find on a google search.

Things I've noticed:

1. Running the setup with no VM (just some three x86) works fine.
2. I've had to adjust some Windows 10 features just to run VirtualBox,
   so I thought maybe the Windows 10 and VBox 5 integration wasn't too
   good, but working with VBox 4 didn't solve it either.

Has anyone else tried a VM included setup with openStack? Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you set up the database?

Comment: What do you mean? The database is set, and I'm able to initiate it - but if I restart the mysqld service, it stops - but fails to start again.

Comment: I mean the database you're authenticating against...wanted to check, if this works. Read the point about this in your post just now: I would first try to fix `mysql`, and debug why it's failing. If `mysql` isn't running, the dashboard can't work.

Comment: that's exactly what I said to myself a while back.... I wasn't able to find the problem so far... Do you have any previous experience with mysql? I'm relatively new in this field, and all the solutions I tried were based on what I could find in forums, google searches etc..... any suggestions?

Comment: :) Yes, I've got experience, but this won't help right now, because we've to work with _your_ environment. I would propose to delete this question, and open up a new one regarding your `mysql` problem, describing the fault and providing logs etc.

Comment: Ok - I'll open a new one, but I think I won't delete this question, since I suspect the problem can be related to the host environment (I'm setting an equivalent setup with this one difference right now) or maybe the network configuration in VBox or it's packets routing in Win-10.